# Why the input file dont shows the text "Browse"?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Im using bootstrap but in the form fields of type file the "Browse" text dont appears, do you know why? It only appears the input like a input text field without any "Browse" button.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col col-lg-6">
    <label for="image">Select an Image</label>
    <label class="custom-file">
      <input type="file" id="file" name="image" value="" class="custom-file-input">
      <span class="custom-file-control"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using? And what browser are you experiencing this on?

Comment: The version 4 of bootstrap on chrome.

Comment: In Chrome, it should read: "Choose File" - are you saying you don't see that?  do you get any errors on the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the below two examples. The issue is that you are using the `custom-file-input` class as opposed to `form-control-file`.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col col-lg-6">
    <label for="image">Select an Image</label>
    <label class="custom-file">
      <input type="file" id="file" name="image" value="" class="custom-file-input">
      <span class="custom-file-control"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Example file input</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
  </div>
</form>
```